# Initial push to a new remote git repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to do an initial push from a local repository to a Gitlab one. The local repository was cloned from an OpenShift one and all the changes are committed and pushed. The Gitlab repository is a fresh one.

```
git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:myorg/myproject.git
git push -u gitlab master
```

I get this error

```
error: object file .git/objects/77/236a32f242ea4e72d54540ac414c798d636d00 is empty
fatal: loose object 77236a32f242ea4e72d54540ac414c798d636d00 (stored in .git/objects/77/236a32f242ea4e72d54540ac414c798d636d00) is corrupt
remote: fatal: early EOF
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:myorg/myproject.git'
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: how did you initialize your local git repo? you seem to have an issue with it

Comment: The local git repo is fetched from another remote. Pushing/pulling to the other remote works perfectly.

Comment: try to delete the broken file `.git/objects/77/236a32f242ea4e72d54540ac414c798d636d00`, backup it just in case

Comment: I did, I get an error for broken link from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I cloned again the original repository (not the gitlab one).

Then running

```
git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:myorg/myproject.git
git push gitlab master
```

worked.

I dropped the corrupted local repo, as all the changes were committed already.

Comment: It's the name of the remote